# JAVA Find parentheses surrounded sections in a String using Matcher/Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, numbers, matcher

I'm using this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)").matcher(strings);
 while(m.find()) {
     double value = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
     sb.append(value);
```

A few lines of Strings might look like this

- Someones name 9/9/2019 209 (20.00) 0.00
- Someones else's name 9/8/2019 310 30.00  0.00
- Another persons name 7/20/2019 220 (10.00) 0.00

Normally I will get an output like

20.000.00

30.000.00

10.000.00

It works fine for the most part, but I'm trying to find numbers that may OR may NOT be surrounded by (parentheses) AND get my out put to include those (parentheses) 
I'm wondering if its as simple as just changing this part
`("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)")`

I tried using 
`\p{Punct}?`  at the beginning and end; obviously, that didn't work.

Comment: Parentheses have a special meaning in regex, so you need to escape them.

Comment: What are all the contexts in which you want to find numbers?  Please add sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the original post. I hope that helps. Thank you for your reply's and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching on the following regex pattern:

```
(?<![^\s()])\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![^\s()])
```

Java code:

```
String input = "Someones name 9/9/2019 209 (20.00) 0.00\nSomeones else's name 9/8/2019 310 30.00 0.00\nAnother persons name 7/20/2019 220 (10.00) 0.00";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(?<![^\\s()])\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?![^\\s()])");
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

This prints:

```
209
20.00
0.00
310
30.00
0.00
220
10.00
0.00
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
(?<![^\s()])  ensure that a word boundary precedes, including space or parentheses
\\d+          match one or more digits
(?:\\.\\d+)?  match an optional decimal component
(?![^\s()])   ensure another word boundary follows
```

Comment: Just updating that I have made some progress 
and that end up answering my own topic soon I think. 
In short..... this line works  
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+\\.\\d+\\)").matcher(strings);

Answer (score 0):

In short..... this line works 
`Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+\\.\\d+\\)").matcher(strings);`
Replace        \\) and \\( with \\s if you only want to find numbers not in brackets